# How do I return the record ID on an insert transaction using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following LINQ to SQL insert code:

```
public static int InsertFileToQueue(FileInfo file)
{
    int? recordID = null; 

    IpsDBDataContext db = new IpsDBDataContext();

    IpsJobFileQueue record = new IpsJobFileQueue();
    record.FileName = file.Name;
    record.FilePath = file.FullName;
    record.PickupDate = file.CreationTime;

    record.StartTime = null;
    record.EndTime = null;
    record.ProcessCode = null;

    db.SubmitChanges();

    return recordID;
}
```

Somewhere after the `db.SubmitChanges()` I know I need to add some code to retrieve the id on the record I just inserted. The things I can't rely on are the filename (as many of these files will be named the same) and certainly not any of the times.

So what do I query for to get the ID?

Comment: Use a SELECT statement.  If you did an INSERT you should be able to then select the ID of the record added.  If you do a SELECT and find a record that matches FileName, FilePath, PickupDate, StartTime, EndTime, ProcessCode if your database schema is valid you should only have one record that matches all those.

Comment: My post states I cant rely on the filename, path or any of those properties as they won't be unique in most cases. CreationTime should be unique, of course.

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of an identity column on your record or the physical record's ROW_NUMBER?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370547/get-id-using-linq-to-sql

Comment: @M.Babcock it would be the physical row id. As far as I can tell there is no ID property on the record object after submitchanges();

Comment: the title contains "transaction" but the question didn't had any !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should call the [Table<TEntity>.InsertOnSubmit(TEntity)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx) method passing the `IpsJobFileQueue` instance to persist. Then, after the [DataContext.SubmitChanges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges.aspx) method has completed, you can retrieve **the assigned primary key value from the corresponding property** on the `IpsJobFileQueue` object.

```
var db = new IpsDBDataContext();
var record = new IpsJobFileQueue();
db.IpsJobFileQueues.InsertOnSubmit(record);
db.SubmitChanges();

return record.Id; // Contains the assigned primary key value
```

In this example `IpsJobFileQueue.Id` is the property that has been [mapped to the primary key column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386963.aspx) of the corresponding database table.

Comment: Given this code, I am getting an error on return record.ID; Its like the property doesnt exist.

Comment: @fullNelson You can get the identity value assigned to the object from the property that, in the model, has been mapped to the primary key column in the database table. That would be the property that has been tagged with the attribute `[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]`.

Comment: The edml where I dropped my tables doesn't list the identity column on the IpsJobFileQueue object (in the designer). So I am not sure how I am supposed to identify the ID (no pun intended) column when it doesn't show up (not even for intellisense). Did I miss a step when making my dbase or my edml?

Comment: @fullNelson You mean the column has not been mapped at all? In that case you can open up the `DBML` file in a text editor and manually add it to the table definition. For example: `<Column Name="Id" Type="System.Int32" DbType="INT NOT NULL" IsPrimaryKey="True" CanBeNull="False" />`. [Here you can read more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399400.aspx) about the XML schema used in the LINQ to SQL models.

Comment: ... it wasn't mapped ... wow... I need to go home... Thanks for showing how to do it through the DBML. And thanks for all your help.